# Getting started on Java EE development

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What IDE do you use and where can I learn to work with the [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the Big Three IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans) are fine. Personally I use IntelliJ.

You probably don't need to do any Java EE beyond having a Web container like Tomcat or Jetty and using Spring plus possibly JPA (eg Hibernate, EclipseLink). There are a plethora of Java Web frameworks that you can put on top of that (eg Struts 2, Wicket, Tapestry, JSF).

The advantage of Java EE is that you can plug pretty much any pieces you want to together (typically using Spring as the glue). The disadvantage is that that is so flexible there isn't really an obvious starting point.

Answer (score 6):

I use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and you can find pretty good tutorial material at the [Oracle Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm).

Answer (score 4):

> what IDE do you use

Me? That's [Eclipse for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php). There are alternatives, like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

> and where can I learn to work with Java EE platform ?

Start with the [Oracle Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm).

Good luck.

---

Seriously, if you're actually interested to learn the Java EE **Web Profile**, then I recommend to read the following questions/answers:

- [What to learn for making Java web applications in Java EE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/1960447#1960447)
- [java web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854)

Answer (score 1):

That's a very wide question. I would recommend to take a look at [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) (dowload the Java EE version) and [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) for IDEs. And at [Oracle's Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/home.htm) to get started with Java EE. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's also a commercial (i.e., not free) version of Eclipse called MyEclipse, which offers a lot of nifty features. Worth consideration.

Jeff