# J2EE Struts,Spring and Hibernate Framework problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

i am going to develop a web application using Struts,Spring and Hibernate. But i have no idea about any of them. Even i know little about JSP and nothing about Servlet. So my question is what to do? I have to learn all those things. But i don't have much time. Normally to learn something i read books on that topics or use tutorials. Now i need links of good tutorials and books on all these. or i need suggestion about how to learn these things. which to learn first and how?

Comment: Are you using applications server? Or why do you write about J2EE? What exactly do you mean by not having much time? What do you know about java?

Comment: i thing i am good at java. i'm using tomcat. i need a overall idea on all these.

Comment: Does it have to be Struts?  There are many more modern web frameworks for Java such as Spring MVC, Wicket, Stripes, ...

Comment: yah it have to be struts

Comment: struts or struts2? when struts2 take a look at the showcases provided with struts2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should forget about Struts, Spring and Hibernate for now.  Put them aside.

The fundamentals are serlvets, JSPs written using JSTL, and JDBC.  Those are the basis for Struts, Spring and Hibernate.  If you don't know those you'll find the frameworks to be totally confusing.

You should do at least one web app using the basic technologies without frameworks.  You'll understand what's being done, and you'll appreciate all that the frameworks do for you.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you suggest me some good tutorials for those.

Answer (score 4):

You can start here official [JavaEE 6 tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/).
You say you know nothing about servlets, so you might want to look at the older [J2EE 1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/index.html) for servlets and jsps.

You might find these helpful:

- [what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/)
- [java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/)
- [important-frameworks-tools-to-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450906/important-frameworks-tools-to-learn/451162#451162)