# How to master Java?

Tags: java

I studied 2 courses in Java:
1- Introduction to programming with Java.
2- Data structures with Java.

In Both courses we used Java SE.

I loved it and I really want to be a great java programmer.

But, I discovered that I should know many technologies involved in Java software development:
Spring, Struts, JSP, JSF, GWT, Hibernate, apache tomcat and many more actually a lot more.

I hope it become simple process like .NET 
you choose one language with one framework and IDE that is it.

Could anyone guide me to the best route or path to master Java, please?
What do you think about these two courses:
http://www.oreillyschool.com/certificates/java-programming.php
and
Advanced Java Certificate Series (from the same school, will be available in September).

Comment: "simple process like .NET".   Very funny.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6

Comment: Mastery takes time, enjoy the ride.

Comment: You're talking about mastering Java development, but you're mentioning frameworks, API's and applications which are all less or more falling in the Java EE web profile category (Java EE web application development). This is a quite different subject than "just" Java (desktop/client) development. I'd suggest to have a look at the link Pascal mentioned here above and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854).

Comment: @S.Lott
I mean by a simple process is that in .NET you have one source for everything.
In Java it seems to me that you have many sources for each thing

Comment: @Fahad: It may seems that way to you.  It's not true, however.  .NET is every bit as complex as Java.  It has to be, or it couldn't do everything Java does.  They're both very, very complex.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think most programmers have about average college graduate intelligence, including myself. What we do have a lot of though is patience.

That said, there are efficient ways to learn and inefficient ways to learn.

- If you're stuck on one tutorial/book, try another book. Once you're done with the basics, there really is no "correct" order to learn.
- Skim through the standard Java library documentation. **Don't bother memorizing it**, but be sure that you know the tools are there when you need them.
- **Make lots of test programs**. If you're ever curious about something, try it out and see what happens. Don't know how big an int is? Write a program that prints out a sizeof. Don't know what happens when you call a virtual function of an override instance? Write a program with two classes, one inheriting the other, and try it out.
- **Read other people's code**. Take note of style and structure. And I don't mean silly things like whether the { should go on the same line as the statement, but how they recycle variables, how they organize their classes, how they use loops, where they bother to optimize and where they don't etc. **Emulate what you like**.
- Practice building "stub" programs -- you can do this in your head once you get the hang of it. Find your favorite program, and write out all the classes/methods as you think would have been used to build it. That'll help you with architecture.
- **Spend lots of time naming your classes**. Don't use fancy names, just descriptive ones. It's a good mental exercise to think about names, even if you don't expect to ever share your code.
- Try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) if you're into that sort of nitty-gritty mathy stuff. I don't believe that programming is all about math, but you might like it.
- Learn C sometime. C++ probably isn't worth it if you're doing java, but C will teach you how your computer works. You don't need to master it, but at least get to the point where you understand memory management and pointers. That'll help you make decisions faster when you want your code to be really fast.
- Learn functional programming someday. Haskell's a good choice, because it's a pure functional language. It's extremely difficult at first, but the concepts you learn from it are valuable regardless of what language you program in. You'll be making design decisions a lot faster, and your code will be a lot more robust.
- **Keep up to date**. Trends come and go in this industry as fast as in the fashion industry. A lot of it is crap, but a lot of it is crucial both to employment and productivity. Always keep an eye out, or you'll go the way of the dinosaurs.

Comment: *"What we do have a lot of though is patience."* - indeed, if you don't have patience, then professional programming is not a good career for you.

Answer (score 14):

The best way to become good at something? Practice, practice, practice.

Don't focus on a single framework just do lots of Java, take a look around open-source projects, find something that needs fixing or implementing and do it or think of something that you want but doesn't exist and make it.

Comment: Yeah, what he said, 48 seconds faster than me.

Comment: What can I say? I've practiced ;)

Comment: How do I practice Java effectively?

Comment: Open source is a good way to get lots of good Java practice. It'll let you see other peoples code and there will normally be a core set of developers who are willing to point out your mistakes.

Answer (score 14):

Practice doesn't make perfect - perfect practice makes perfect.  If you continue to make the same mistakes, you'll only succeed in developing bad habits.

You need to read [this](http://norvig.com/21-days.html).

Your Java roadmap ought to look like this:

1. Concentrate on core Java JDK classes to start.  Don't worry about Java EE until you're comfortable with interfaces, classes, and the basics.  JDBC is an important part of core Java, so be fluent with it.  You'll have to know about relational databases, normalization, and SQL.  GUI technology here is Swing.
2. Once you have that, take up servlets, JSPs written using JSTL exclusively (no scriptlets), and JDBC.  You'll have to understand something about Tomcat (or another servlet/JSP engine), HTTP, HTML, CSS, and a little JavaScript as well.  You can go a very long way with just these.
3. Once you've mastered 1 and 2, you'll have to make a choice of framework.  I'd recommend either swallowing Spring or EJB 3 whole.  I'd recommend Spring first, but I'll admit that I don't know EJB 3 well.

Comment: Would "deliberate practice" fit the bill?

Comment: "Deliberately good practice" - yes.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it thousands of times.

Answer (score 7):

I get the impression from the phrasing of your question that Java is your first programming language. I laud your desire to "master Java", but if I might, I'd like to suggest that you try a little breadth before you get too much depth!

It's easy, I think, with a CS degree where most courses are taught in Java, to fall into the trap of believing that all programming languages are:

- object-oriented (and with single implementation inheritance and multiple interface inheritance)
- statically-typed (with no type-inference)
- imperative (i.e. making use of iteration constructs and mutable state)
- verbose

and therefore that all programming must look roughly like Java programming.

I'd humbly suggest doing some reading on different paradigms and languages: learn a dynamically typed language (coming from Java, I'd suggest Python or Ruby), learn a non-OO language (like C)---and implement OO, learn about functional programming (Haskell's a great eye-opener). At least take a look around before diving head-first into Java alphabet soup (Java culture highly values acronyms---but I'll pass no value judgments on this here).

Just my US $0.02!

Answer (score 3):

Write programs in it.  Find open source programs that use it and fix their bugs and add functionality to them.  The best way to get experience is to experience it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know what you should be studying, within the realm of your examples (Spring, Struts, JSP, JSF, GWT, Hibernate, apache tomcat), then find some podcasts and blog posts that allow you to survey these technologies.  You can then choose the ones you are most interested in for further study.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other two respondents (practice, particularly with open-source projects, is the best way to get good at a language). However, I wanted to add one thing. It's unclear from your answer how much experience you have with object-oriented design, and with Java, that's essential. I'd recommend looking into advanced OO design to get a sense for what's out there. My favorite book on OO design is available for free and linked below - see if it's at your level. If not, find something more/less advanced and work from it.

http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/oodesign/build-java/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Java Technologies are very vast, from mobile phones, to enterprise level servers.  You might want to first narrow what you want to learn.

Your first talk about Java SE(applications programming) and then start mixing in Java J2EE, and Java EJB.

If you want to go down the web route or enterprise server then you need to learn J2EE,EJB,Hibernate,Spring,etc otherwise these technologies aren't seen as often when programming applications.

It still seems like you have a long road to go, probably the most beneficial for you to learn next would be Java Swing(gui).

Answer (score 0):

Practice and learn frameworks as you need them (or come across them).  There are way too many frameworks out there (for Java and for .NET) to learn in one shot.

Learning the standard Java class libraries is always a start

Answer (score 0):

The best way to become good at something? Get a job that allows you to use that technology. Get paid while practicing.

There is a time to stop reading books and articles, and get to work building a project.

As you are working, learn from others who are better than you. Continue to read articles on topics that interest you, and apply what you learn at work.

Comment: Actually, It is hard here to find an entry level Java job.
Today, I had a phone interview with a company looking for Java programmer with no experience and I was asked about the above mentioned technologies plus others more.

Answer (score 0):

Find a mentor and pick his/her brains often. Once you are working in the field ask for code reviews from senior developers. This will get you out of your own habits, and reading people's suggestions for how you can improve will give you plenty of insights. Don't sit around reading, solve problems on a per-problem basis and work your way up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that easy to became a master in Java, what i have done to study java is 
1)try to convert all the apps i have seen into java,
eg:paint to java 
2)used to went to JAVA user groups and conference in my state
3)Went to Groups in Goolge for checking Codes of Java
thats all i do, i cant say i am the master, but i am able to do the stuff