# Starting a project in Java EE

Tags: java-ee-6

I am thinking of using Java EE for my college project. Previously, I have used C# for a desktop application.  I am new to Java and Java EE.

My question is this.  What do I have to consider before starting a project in Java EE? I am thinking about using NetBeans as my IDE.  Is this a good idea?  I can choose either MS Sql Server or Oracle as my back end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do I have to consider before starting a project in Java EE?

This question is very broad and I don't know if this is exactly the expected answer but my suggestion would be to go for Java EE 6 (more precisely, for the **Java EE 6 Web Profile** which is a subset of the entire specification but should be more than enough in your case) and to use the following APIs:

- JSF 2.0 for the presentation layer.
- EJB 3.1 Lite for the services layer.
- JPA 2.0 for the persistence of your domain objects.

For the runtime environment (the server to run the code), I suggest using [GlassFish 3.0.1 Web Profile](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html).

> I am thinking about using NetBeans as my IDE. Is this a good idea?

That would be my recommendation. NetBeans is a very decent IDE, is beginner friendly IDE (but still powerful), it provides very good support for Java EE 6, very good integration with GlassFish, and has are plenty of tutorials and documentation available to get started:

- [Getting Started with Java EE 6 Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html)
- [Java EE & Java Web Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html)

> I can choose either MS Sql Server or Oracle as my back end.

Java uses an unified low level API called JDBC (JPA being a higher level API built on top of it) to interact with a database so choosing one or the other doesn't really matter from a Java point of view and it won't make any difference for a college project so pick the one you want to work with (if you already used SQL Server for your C# project, you might want to get some experience with Oracle).

#### Related questions

- [What to learn for making Java web applications in Java EE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/1960447#1960447)

Comment: The kind of answers that let you start doing something rather than re-asking the same question elsewhere. Of course +1