# How to create website using java

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jdbc

I have created a web page which has a form using HTML. I validate the entries made by the user using javascript, and then I read the data entered using `doPost` method of `HttpServlet`. Now, I want to store this data in a database. How do I proceed? What new things should I learn? Where does JSP and JDBC SQL come into picture? I am a newbie and trying to learn and implement.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to store this data in a database. How do I proceed?

You need to [learn](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/) [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity), it's an API which provides methods to communicate with the database. [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) [Structure Query Language] is a language which is used to communicate with the database, you write your queries in SQL to extract & insert data to & fro from db. The best resource to start with SQL in opinion would be [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

JSP forms the view of the application. Each thing has its respective role.

Check out the image 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084591/how-should-i-start-java-based-web-development)** question has some good answers as to how to go about learning Java based web development.

Either way, you have to start with **Servlets** and as for **JSP**, architecturally, JSP may be viewed as a high-level abstraction of Java servlets. JSPs are translated into servlets at runtime.

Then **and only then** move on to web frameworks. **[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java)** compares different Java web frameworks out there. My personal preference is **Spring MVC**, it's also the most popular.

Learn what an **[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)** does and then move on to **[Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29)** which is an ORM for Java..